# How to get OData navigation properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, odata

In my `OData` controller, I have methods like this :

```
// GET odata/Fixtures(5)
public SingleResult<Fixture> GetFixture([FromODataUri] int key)
{
    return SingleResult.Create(db.Fixtures.Where(fixture => fixture.FixtureId == key));
}

// GET odata/Fixtures(5)/City
[Queryable]
public SingleResult<City> GetCity([FromODataUri] int key)
{
    return SingleResult.Create(db.Fixtures.Where(m => m.FixtureId == key).Select(m => m.City));
}

// GET odata/Fixtures(5)/Team
[Queryable]
public SingleResult<Team> GetTeam([FromODataUri] int key)
{
    return SingleResult.Create(db.Fixtures.Where(m => m.FixtureId == key).Select(m => m.Team));
}
```

How do I get at the City and Team in `AngularJs` from the Fixtures collection?  This does not get them :

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="fixture in fixtures | orderBy:'FixtureId'" id="fixture_{{fixture.id}}">
        <td>{{fixture.FixtureId}}</td>
        <td>{{fixture.City.CityName}}</td>
        <td>{{fixture.Team.TeamName}}</td>
        ...
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Do I need to reference `GetCity` and `GetTeam` in `GetFixture` to return a DTO that would look something like :

```
class FixtureDTO
{
    public int FixtureId { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }
    public string TeamName { get; set; }
}
```

And if so does someone have an example of how I would do that? Or am I approaching this in the wrong way entirely?

Any advice would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use $expand odata keyword to include navigation properties in server response to query Fixtures.
Doing so your client code must work.